# How to make Java use my classloader for class resolution

Tags: java, classloader

Test case below. Output:

```
custom loading of: pkg.TestRun
ran.
wish this would run in my custom classloader
```

What I want to happen is to see "custom loading of: pkg.TestRun" show up between the second and third lines of the output.

How can I get it to load the dependencies of a class from my custom classloader, even when the first class is loaded from the parent? Note, that in my real case, I get a class not found exception because the equivalent of OtherClass is not known to the parent classloader.

I know one solution is to have the custom class loader explicitly load TestRun. However, how to load TestRun is already known to the parent classloader and I don't want to have to manage finding it separately since it's already done and it might be tricky for me to somehow figure that out when it's already being managed without me doing anything. And I've tried to do something like super.getResource (returns null) or findClass (already sets parent as classloader for it) but neither worked.

So, can I let the parent find the class, but the custom loader define it? Or, is there just a way to make it so that it will always use my custom loader to look for dependencies?

```
package pkg;

public class TestCL {

    static class MyCL extends ClassLoader {
        MyCL(ClassLoader parent) {
            super(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public Class loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            System.out.println("custom loading of: " + name);
            return getParent().loadClass(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyCL cl = new MyCL(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
        cl.loadClass("pkg.TestRun").getMethod("run", new Class[] {}).invoke(null);
    }
}

class TestRun {
    public static void run() {
        System.out.println("ran.");
        OtherClass.runAlso();
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    public static void runAlso() {
        System.out.println("wish this would run in my custom classloader");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a custom class loader?

Comment: The `-verbose:class` command line option is your friend when you're trying to debug class loading issues.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see 'custom loading of OtherClass'? I would use the debugger to find what is loading OtherClass in the main classloader.

Comment: I need a custom classloader because loading dynamically created classes on the fly. I already know which loader is loading OtherClass, it's the parent loader.

Comment: Yes but the debugger will show you why it's being loaded by the parent loader ie the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the parent classloader (or the one that already knows where it is) to read the bytes of the class, then define it in the custom class loader.

So, something like this:

```
public static byte[] loadBytesForClass(ClassLoader loader, String fqn) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = loader.getResourceAsStream(fqn.replace(".", "/") + ".class");
    if (input == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not load bytes for class: " + fqn);
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StringUtil.copy(input, output);
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Then you can call `defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length)` with those bytes to define it in the custom class loader.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was you were not loading anything using your custom classloader
It asks it parent to load the class, so everything was being loaded by the main classloader.

Try this modified code:

```
package stackoverflow.june2012.classloader;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class TestCL {

static class MyCL extends URLClassLoader {
    MyCL(URL[] urls) {
        // NOTE: No parent classloader!
        super(urls, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Class loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("custom loading of: " + name);
        return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("findClass: " + name);
        System.out.println("NOTE: Only called if this classloader does NOT have a parent");
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new File("./bin").toURI().toURL();
    System.out.println("url to search for classes: " + url);
    MyCL cl = new MyCL(new URL[] {url});
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
    Class loadClass = cl.loadClass("stackoverflow.june2012.classloader.TestRun");
    System.out.println("Loaded TestRun using classloader: " + loadClass.getClassLoader());
    loadClass.getMethod("run", new Class[] {}).invoke(null);
}
```

}

And I had to move your other 2 classes into a separate file, otherwise it cant be accessed as it was package-private in a different classloader:

```
package stackoverflow.june2012.classloader;

public class TestRun {
    public static void run() {
    System.out.println("ran.");
    OtherClass.runAlso();
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    public static void runAlso() {
        System.out.println("wish this would run in my custom classloader");
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that requires me to know the URLs that would find TestRun. This I want to avoid which is why I said: "I know one solution is to have the custom class *loader* explicitly load TestRun. However, it's already known to the parent classloader and I don't want to have to manage finding it separately since it's already done." Though I see a mistake (added *loader*) in there which I have now fixed.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I think the answer is "no". You have to get your custom classloader to do all the work. If a classloader has loaded a class then it will load all it's dependencies, as far as I know. Finding the URL could be done a number of ways, I just did it a really easy way in my example. For real code, you could (for example) scan for a known .class file and construct the custom classloader's URL from that.